# Creating field on each node

Tags: nodes, 8, navigation

I want to add a field on each node which links to a particular page where module's controller will act. I want to actually add a link at bottom of node, and I want to do this programmatically. But I am not able to start, and I am very new to this.

Any ideas or suggestions to get me started? Or give me some reference in Drupal core modules or some other type of sample code to do so?
I have done this till now to add the link:

```
function module_entity_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode, $langcode) {
if (TRUE) {
  $entity->content['links']['module'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'links__entity__module',
      '#links' => $link_builder->buildLinks($entity),
    );
 }
}
```

but till now got no success. Am I using correct hook?Also I think that now the question makes sense.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail on this?

Comment: @SumitMadan basically I want to add a link at bottom of node.

Comment: You can add a link field by adding link module. No?

Comment: @SumitMadan yeah we can do so but how to do so programatically?

Comment: By writing a custom module, use `hook_node_insert` to insert the link in field. Or if its a static link then just use template, or `hook_node_view`.

Comment: @SumitMadan Thanks, can u please give me some reference in the core or some code for same.

Comment: That you have to google it.

Comment: @SumitMadan I made some attempts but still no success. Can u suggest something?

Comment: If you have a link field added in your content type, then there is no need to programmatically render the field. As I understand from your comment, you need to programmatically add a field value. You can achieve it implementing `hook_node_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\ EntityInterface $node)`.

Comment: I have answer it. Please check.